# How to mix 2 Material into geometry nodes?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I would like to mix 2 materials with the geometry nodes, just like I did in the left material example, where, via a mix node which in this case I am using to simulate 2 different Red / Green materials.

I'd like to Use 2 Red / Verse materials in the Geometry Node, and do the same.

I find the "Replace Material" node very nice but I don't think it's possible to do it with it. I made this visual example to make it easier to explain what I would like to do.

Anyone have any idea if this is possible and how?

[image]

Comment: You could use the same shader editor "Mix Idea" material and use the set material node in geometry nodes to use that material in geometry nodes?

Comment: The idea is to use 2 different materials and mix them in geometric nodes

Comment: Why do you need to use GN for such thing? GN assigns material based on geometry (vertices) ... so the purpose matters.

Comment: @vklidu I agree with what you said, and if animation is required, the values can easily be edited. I guess this is more of a feature question (to ask if its possible) rather than a question where there really is a problem.

Comment: I would still appreciate if you can answer my comment. To offer solution that fits to your needs we need to know more about Why GN and How do you plan to use it. Because like I said ... for such sharp material edge you need to generate some how vertices at that place (if the Factor for split has to be GN parametr).

Comment: @vklidu My example consists of a Map Range, which depending on the setting can make the deadline +/- marked. I would like to reproduce the same situation Identical with the Geometry Nodes (If possible) The aim is to obtain the same situation that I am obtaining with the material node tree

Comment: if this is your only one point, than go by Chris's way ...

Answer (score 7):

Inside GN system is material assigned according to geometry (group of vertices/faces). For such sharp material mix you need vertices at that place (or generate them).

Here is an example with **Boolean** operation. *Plane* is used as Factor to control location / rotation... by rotation or moving plane you generate vertices dynamicly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great setup, +1!

Comment: Good job. But unfortunately I don't like dealing with external objects. I would have preferred to manage through a Procedural node

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 5):

do you mean like so?

[image]

You have to subdivide the default cube one time to get this result.

[image]

Comment: I've been avoiding geometry nodes for quite a long time now... But the answers here make me feel they're not that hard, I guess. Good answer though, +1

Comment: @YousufChaudhry: thank you...although i am not sure that this is what the OP wants....

Comment: I think this _is_ what the OP wants, but side question: Why don't geometry nodes have shader nodes or any texture coordinate? Since there is a Mix RGB node, so it's really hard to find out the purpose of it. O tried using geo node's mix rgb as a solution but it turned out there was no shader to plug it into :D

Comment: i have no idea...but i hope it will come ;) the mix rgb node is pretty handy if you want to e.g. animate from one position to another (so you can misuse it as an easy way to move a point along a line via fac)

Comment: Wait... Do you literally mean I can use a node even if I have a red line as an output? Or does it work without a red line output? As far as I know, the mix rgb has only colour outputs and only one fac output (not that I'm saying I need more factor inputs, but maybe that would be useful to have a factor for a factor for a factor?)

Comment: you can plug e.g. position into mixrgb because position has 3 floats and rgb as well. Geonodes doesn't use alpha values for rgb....but no, you cannot use red lines as output

Comment: @Chris Yes, but I can't reproduce that situation, I added a Math (Add) node to adjust the deadline height, but I can't adjust the height. The whole thing looks "Snappy"

Comment: You need more vertices to "snap" in shorter steps ... see blend file (I added subdivision node and merge Thresholds into Value node to set it easier. Or you would have to add some math to position middle vertices up&down depending on Threshold value to sync height.

Comment: Uh, Ok, So this technique, necessarily requires a subdivision of the mesh as I tested from the file.blend This is very interesting. The problem is that I don't want to subdivide the meshes, the same is true for a material like in my example, it doesn't require subdivision. Maybe this is not yet possible with Geometry nodes

Comment: That is what I'm trying to say from the first comment under your Q. With GN you operate on geometry level ... So I don't think it would be different in a future. What you are asking for are designed Shader nodes.